# Add multiple items to zset with phpredis zadd

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I am trying to figure out how add multiple items to zset via the phpredis zadd method. Something like the following

`ZADD myzset 2 "two" 3 "three"`

Comment: I assume you mean *in PHP*, considering the redis command you provided is correct.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#zadd), you can pass the pairs of score/value.

```
$redis->zAdd('myzset', 2, 'two', 3, 'three');
```

Comment: Description: Add one or more members to a sorted set or update its score if it already exists
- looks like completely missed this part. Thanks!